# How to import CSV to Trello

Tags: csv, trello

I have a .csv file that I want to import to Trello. How can I go about doing that? Zapier won´t work because there are too many and I would be required to pay, which I´m trying to avoid.

Comment: there is a free power-up now which does this, including custom field data https://www.bluecatreports.com/imports/

Answer (score 15):

It's been some time since I used it, but this was killer:

[Online Scrum Tools – Part 3 – Import Backlog into Trello](http://www.littlebluemonkey.com/blog/online-scrum-tools-part-3-upload-existing-product-backlog-into-trello)

Basically, it's a Google Docs Spreadsheet with some custom JavaScript in it. You set it up with your Trello API Key, the Board ID, and the List ID, and it does the magic.

Comment: This was very helpful. Still works as of 2016.10.05.

Comment: Still working as of 27-sep-2017

Comment: Man! Was this awesome. Thank you. Still working as of Feb 27, 2018.

Comment: still works in March 2020

Answer (score 2):

You can do this via the [Import Wizard](https://wizard.import2.com), by Import2 (disclaimer, I work for Import2). This will import your lists from CSV directly into Trello and there is no limit on number of items.

Answer (score 0):

Official Trello recommendation: https://help.trello.com/article/751-importing-data-into-trello

1. **Copy Paste** - When you paste text into a Trello card, each new line becomes a new card. This means if you have a list of card titles e.g. in an Excel spreadsheet, you can simply copy the title from one column and each cell from the sheet will become a card in a Trello list.
2. [Trello API](https://trello.com/docs) - You can use the Trello API to have full programmatic control of the import process
3. [Zapier](https://info.trello.com/power-ups/zapier)
4. [Import2 Wizard](https://wizard.import2.com/apps/trello) - is a third party solution that allows you to import data in Trello from CSV files.

Bonus: Custom python script (thanks yo Joshm Carthur) https://gist.github.com/joshmcarthur/2839352#file-trello-cards-from-csv-rb

Comment: This exports from Trello, not INTO Trello